# Proof: Minkowski sum polytope implies A and B polytopes

Tags: geometry, polyhedra, discrete-geometry, polytopes

Suppose $A$ and $B$ are convex sets and their Minkowski sum $A+B$ is a polytope. 
How do you prove that $A$ and $B$ are polytopes as well?

Answer (score 3):

HINT:

$A+B$ being a polytope, it is the convex of finitely many points $a_i + b_i$, $1\le i \le n$, where $a_i \in A$ and $b_i \in B$. Let $\tilde A = \text{Co}( a_i)$, $\tilde B = \text{Co}(b_i)$. One checks right away that $\tilde A + \tilde B \supset A+B$ and therefore we have the equality 
$$\tilde A + \tilde B = A+B$$

while $\tilde A \subset A$ and $\tilde B \subset B$.  From here one shows that $\tilde A = A$ and $\tilde B = B$ ( reduce to the case of $\dim =1$).

Comment: Just want to comment you can also use the support functions to check the last step. (Instead of reducing to dim 1. Though maybe using support functions is similar morally, since it reduces the problem to understanding linear functionals, with codomain one dimensional...)

Comment: @AreaMan: Yes, I think that is the way, good point!